# Center list items

Tags: html, css

I have created a list that contains movie cases and a title beneath each case. However, I can't get the list items to center themselves.

Here's what it looks like: 
[image]

Here's what I want it to look like:
[image]

In the following CSS rules, I have centered `#main-container` with `margin: 0 auto`

```css
#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

However, that just centers `#main-container`, not the list items.

I think it has something to do with this CSS rule.

```css
.element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qo6zL6f/)

```css
#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#movies-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#movies-container li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.cover {
  background: grey;
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
}
.element img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.element .title {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <ul id="movies-container">
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working Solution for Internet Explorer too**

If you give `float` it doesn't work out. Check this out:

**Preview**

[image]

**Snippet**

```css
#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#movies-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#movies-container li {
  list-style:none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.cover {
  background: grey;
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
}

.element img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.element .title {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <ul id="movies-container">
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>    <li class="element">
    <div class="cover">
      <a href="#"><img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6qo6zL6f/3/**

Comment: Wow, I didn't know text-align could work with elements in a list like that. I thought it only worked with text. Thank you very much for the help and great solution!

Comment: @JoshPotter Yes, here we are converting the list to a text element, using `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Hate to bother you but for some odd reason I also noticed there is some spacing added when using inline-block. It actually affects my entire page. Do you know how I could get rid of this? I tried font-size: 0; like most suggested but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: Yes, you can do. @JoshPotter Just don't give spaces between the `<li>`. Do this: `</li><li>`

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a saint!

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox works fine for the solution.

**Added CSS**

```
#movies-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap; /* Wrap to next line */
  justify-content: center; /* Center all rows */
}
```

Check the [**Browser compatibility table**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) for Flexbox

```css
#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#movies-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#movies-container li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.element {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
}
.cover {
  background: grey;
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
}
.element img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.element .title {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <ul id="movies-container">
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would achieve the effect you're looking for, the main differences are using `inline-block` on `.element` and `text-align: center` on `#main-container`.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#main-container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#movies-container,
.element {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#movies-container {
    font-size: 0;
}
.element {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 7.5px;
}
.cover {
  background: grey;
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
}
.element img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 130px;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}
.element .title {
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-container">
  <ul id="movies-container">
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">300</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/12244.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">9</div>
    </li>
    <li class="element">
      <div class="cover">
        <img src="http://cparliaros.com/imdb/img/thumbnails/1271.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="title">Gladiator</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```